# Programmable usb host to host controller

Tags: embedded, usb, microcontroller, spoofing

Further to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4940825/spoofing-a-game-controller) question, I'm looking for a device that will allow me to connect two USB hosts, while still being fully programmable. I would like something that can do the following:

Masquerade as an arbitrary USB device

Take input from a PC and do nothing but pass it on to the other host.

I've been looking for a microcontroller (preferably pre-assembled) that will allow me to do this, but have so far come up blank. Does anyone know of a controller (preferably cheap) that will allow me to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spoofing a game controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4940825/spoofing-a-game-controller)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Take input from a PC and do nothing but pass it on to the other host.

This is non-sensical from a USB perspective. USB is a host-based protocol: a device will never send data unless a host requests it first. Keep in mind here, 'host' and 'device' have specific meanings here within the protocol itself; you can think of a 'host' as the master and the 'device' as the slave. These roles are baked into a USB controller. There is no way to convince a standard USB controller in any given PC or peripheral to swap roles. There are add-in cards for PCs that are USB device controllers (making your PC act as a device), but 'cheap' is not a word I would use to describe them.

What you really are trying to do is create something that is a USB device to device bridge. So, alright, you need to have two USB(2.0) device controllers (maybe not that expensive, some micros already have to on-the-go controllers). Then you have to get them to pass something meaningful to each other. That's really hard because, as I mentioned above, hosts must tell a device to send data, and can send data to a device whenever it wants. Assuming a game controller shows up as a HID device (assuming the console doesn't listen for some weird, custom descriptor, and use some weird, custom protocol), interrupt pipes will be used to transfer data. This pipe is guaranteed to be polled at some minimum rate. So you have the console requesting data at some rate, which is not fixed, and a host-as-gamepad sending data at some rate. It's going to impossible for the two to sync up, so you'll need some kind of decent sized buffer on the gadget you're trying to create, which adds more $$ and more complexity.

USB is also pretty fast. In high-speed (USB2.0), frames are 125 microseconds long. That means you have to be completing requests at around 8KHz, which seems slow compared to the clock speed of a microcontoller, but keep in mind you have to be doing everything else at once. I'm not sure if there's a hobbyist-level microcontroller that's going to have everything you need, especially one for which you don't need to roll your own USB stack.

Comment: Yes, that is the point. Perhaps I didn't explain myself well enough. On receiving an answer to my earlier question, I read up on USB. So I know that connecting two hosts directly is impossible. I am looking for a device which has both one or more OTG controllers + some other way to connect to it (Wifi/bluetooth/ethernet). I believe I *might* be able to pull it off with a GuruPlug devkit (http://www.globalscaletechnologies.com/p-40-guruplug-display-devkit.aspx), but this is over budget at the moment (I'm looking for something at 1/2 the price), so I guess I'll need to put it on hold.

Comment: Why do you need some other way to connect to it? Wifi/BT/Ether are pretty expensive ways to go about it. Would a plain 'ol UART not be fast enough?

Comment: Console(Host)<---(OTG)Device(OTG)--->(Host)PC. If the device only has one OTG, then you need an interface that both the PC and the device possess to communicate. Console(Host)<---(OTG)Device(Wifi/Bluetooth/Ethernet)--->PC(Wifi/Bluetooth/Ethernet). Alternatively, you could connect the keyboard/mouse to the device itself, but this is, as you say, likely to require quite a substantial amount of processing power and memory on the device itself.

Comment: If the controllers are never switching roles, they don't need to be OTG. I think you can get a decently beefy micro with a USB device controller for not too much (probably the hardest part is finding something in a package you can work with). Use serial or SPI to talk to the chip, sending it info about what to send the console, and then have the chip do a little translation and handle the USBHID stuff.

Comment: Which brings me back to my original question, can you suggest a good microcontroller for this?

Comment: Of course a device can send data without the host requesting it. How would USB MIDI devices work otherwise ?

Comment: Polling. http://www.usb.org/developers/devclass_docs/midi10.pdf Note the "bInterval" fields in the endpoint descriptors - that's the requested polling interval.

Comment: Yes, but the request to send data is still initiated from the device. That it is done at specific intervals at which the host polls is actually irrelevant. I guess we're talking potato, potatoe here.

Comment: @Miles : Also, if you check the docs you see that bInterval is ignored for bulk endpoints. MIDI data are sent over bulk endpoints.

Comment: I'm sorry, but it's not a matter of opinion. A device can never send data to host without the host requesting it. Universal Serial Bus Revision 2.0 specification, section 4.4: "The USB is a polled bus. The Host Controller initiates all data transfers." Think about what would happen with multiple devices on a hub: without a master initiating all transfers USB devices would need to deal with collisions in a vastly more complex way. Keep in mind one of the primary goals of USB was to be cheap for device manufacturers to implement with current (1996) technology.

Answer (score 1):

Try this chip -> FTDI 232 they are protocols chips, it will translate the data to i2c, spi, serial, whatever u want. nice, easy and cheap :) . FTDI firm, have even better ones (vinculum), with otg and everything u need but I would start with the FTDI232. U just need to use your favorite uC to do the work u want. ... on the other hand, u have to do a little board, maybe some soldering, :). good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You will need $$$$ in equipment and $$$$$ in development work to achieve things the way you imagine. You should better tell us what do you want to emulate, and take a look [here](http://www.obdev.at/products/vusb/prjhid.html) if someone has already done it for you. If not then use LUFA library with some bigger USB AVR that can behave as USB host and connect two of them (one as USB guest and the other as USB host) via some other protocol (I2C/SPI/UART).

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime there is a great solution for this Problem. Using the [FaceDancer Library](https://github.com/usb-tools/Facedancer) together with one of the boards supported by this great piece of software (i.E. [GreatFET One](https://greatscottgadgets.com/greatfet/)) you get exactly what you want:

The GreatFET One has two USB connectors: the first one is used to simulate ANY kind of USB Device, while the second one is used to forward all requests/responses received/send via the first connector.

Of course this tool requires that you know the USB protocol of the device you want to simulate. Although there are some code samples you still have to know what you are doing as soon as you customize them.